# VSCode problem showing paths in folder /run/user/1000/doc

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, snap

I recently got a problem in VSCode after updating to v1.77.3 where the path for new projects is wrong, while for old projects it's correct.

In particular, new projects are opened in folders prefixed with `/run/user/100/doc/` followed by a sha256 like digest that varies per folder.

Usually new projects were opened where I wanted them to be, in my home folder `~/`

I'm using Ubuntu Linux and installed vscode through snap.

Comment: A Snap issue perhaps? Try installing non-snap VSC.

Comment: will i lose my configuration?

Comment: No idea, but copying `settings.json`, `keybindings.json` and installing extensions again should be simple.

Comment: yes it's working, but old projects are still with the '/run/user/1000/...' path. Do you have any idea how to fix them? and how to fix the VSC snap? Note also that configuration didn't change after installation from .deb

Comment: Nope, don't know.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75209621/permission-error-linux-parrot-os-even-root-user-cant-access-that-file-folder and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/162911/377222

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in VSCode 1.77 that seems to have been fixed in VSCode 1.78.

So get your update and you should be fine.

Relevant VS code Github issue: [New saved files show breadcrumb path as /run/user](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/180004)